# Opening files with VB.NET program

Tags: vb.net

I recently learned how to use VB.NET to set your program as the default for a chosen extension. You would write code to set a registry value. The problem is, when you open the file - after setting your program as default - it just opens your program (like a shortcut would). Is there a way that you could make it actually open the file? So say I have a text file. I set the default program for .txt files to my application. How would I make it load the text file, when I click to open the file, like you can if notepad is set to the default? If this doesn't make sense, just let me know.

Comment: It might help people if you give a code sample showing the name of the function you've written that opens the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the file is passed to your program as a command line parameter. Your program will need to read the command line parameters and react accordingly.

Here is some example code demonstrating how to read the command line parameters:

```
  Sub Main()
    Dim s() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    ' write code to open the file here...
    Console.WriteLine(s(1))
  End Sub
```

To help with debugging this you can specify command-line arguments in the Visual Studio IDE:

1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
2. Click the Debug tab.
3. In the Command line arguments field, enter the command-line arguments you wish to use.

Comment: My program is a GUI. I don't think you can add modules.

Comment: The important part is the System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() which gets an array of command line parameters.

Comment: Slight problem... System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() is not a string. I just added `.ToString`. will this still work?

Comment: It's array of strings.. use System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(1)

Comment: Or (if you want to be able to deal with more than one file) use a loop to process the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare your `Sub Main` to receive the command line arguments:

```
Sub Main(Args() As String)

End Sub
```

Comment: Good one, this is the easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

The filename is passed to your program by the OS

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
EndSub
```

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)