# VB : How to start my program and read a file by click the file in 'File Explorer'?

Tags: vb.net, file, startup

I know how to write and read file. I put some code to open my own file. If I want to open file, I can click "File > Open" in my program. It had not problem about it.

However I want to develop my program to be better that. In general program, when click file in File Explorer, the program will start and read the file. Example I click ".avi" video file and my default program will start and play video.

I try that in my program. The save file for my program is ".mmr" binary file. I don't have problem to save it and I can open it correctly by click "File > Open" in my program. I set my program at default to open ".mmr" in File Explorer. When I double click ".mmr" file in File Explorer, my program starts, but nothing happens after that. I know I didn't put code to read file when my program starts.

This is my source code.

```
Public strFileLocation As String 'File location

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub subOpen()

'There are code to read my '.mmr' file.

'I didn't use parameter. I use variable for file location because my program is too complex to use parameter for it.
'strFileLocation should be the open file location.

End Sub
```

How to make program knows it starts with open file (read file after program starts) or without open file (nothing to do)?

How to strFileLocation gets the open file location (the file that I click in File Explorer)?

Comment: Explorer will pass the file to your app on the CommandLine.

Comment: [**Here's an example**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14944020/3740093) of getting the Command Line args.

Comment: Thanks. That help me so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it in command lines. you can access to command lines by `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`